# Why does SystemVerilog think 0.001 == 0?

Tags: system-verilog

I'm trying to take the absolute value of a number. C, Python, Matlab, etc. all have this kind of thing built in, but in Verilog you have to make your own. So I write this:

```
function abs(shortreal x);
    if (x >= 0.0) begin 
        abs = x;
    end else begin 
        abs = -1 * x;
    end
endfunction
```

Nothing to screw up, right?

For some reason that is mysterious to me, this function is returning 0 when passed 0.001. How is this possible? 0.001 is obviously > 0. Moreover, it's far enough away from 0 that rounding error should not be a factor. The `if` statement should evaluate to true and abs = 0.001.

Does anyone know what is going on? Is this one of those things where the SV standard leaves a lot to the imagination so different language implementations behave differently? Sim is running on ModelSim 2020.1_3 in case it matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you did not explicitly declare the return type of your function, it  returns a 1-bit value of type `logic`.  This means that `abs` can only be the integer values 0 or 1, not a floating-point value (ignoring values `x` and `z` for this discussion).

You should change it to the desired return type, presumably `shortreal`:

Change:

```
function abs(shortreal x);
```

to:

```
function shortreal abs(shortreal x);
```

This behavior is clearly defined in the standard.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 13.4 *Functions*:

> In particular, the implicit syntax can be empty, in which case the
> return type is a **logic** scalar.

This shows that `abs(0.001)` returns `0.001`:

```
module tb;

function shortreal abs(shortreal x);
    if (x >= 0.0) begin 
        abs = x;
    end else begin 
        abs = -1 * x;
    end
endfunction

initial begin
    shortreal a;
    a = abs(0.001);
    #1 $display(a);
end

endmodule
```